# Question on the karp reduction (many-one reduction)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, computational-complexity

I have encountered a question and breaking my head on it,

Prove or disprove:
For every two decision problems S_1,S_2∉{∅,{0,1}^*} if there is a karp reduction from S_1  to S_2 so there is a karp reduction from S_2  to S_1

Thanks for the helpers

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think "Community" is being silly; the only issues I see with the question are that "so" should be "then" (perhaps an awkward translation from German) and "Karp" should be capitalized (a proper name). As a hint: Consider what happens if $S_1$ is solvable in polynomial time and $S_2$ is not.